# Session container not working in zf2?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I have seen many questions on StackOverflow and I have this code

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

public function indexAction() {

     $userSession = new Container('user');
     $userSession->username = 'Sandhya';
     return new ViewModel();
     }
}
```

When I am printing the `$userSession` container in the controller it is giving me this output

```
Zend\Session\Container Object ( 
    [name:protected] => user 
    [manager:protected] => Zend\Session\SessionManager Object (
        [defaultDestroyOptions:protected] => Array ( 
            [send_expire_cookie] => 1 
            [clear_storage] => 
        ) 
        [name:protected] => 
        [validatorChain:protected] => 
        [config:protected] => Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig Object (
            [phpErrorCode:protected] => 
            [phpErrorMessage:protected] => 
            [rememberMeSeconds:protected] => 240 
            [serializeHandler:protected] => 
            [validCacheLimiters:protected] => Array (
                [0] => nocache 
                [1] => public 
                [2] => private 
                [3] => private_no_expire 
            ) 
            [validHashBitsPerCharacters:protected] => Array ( 
                [0] => 4 
                [1] => 5 
                [2] => 6 
            ) 
            [validHashFunctions:protected] => 
            [name:protected] => 
            [savePath:protected] => 
            [cookieLifetime:protected] => 2592000 
            [cookiePath:protected] => 
            [cookieDomain:protected] => 
            [cookieSecure:protected] => 
            [cookieHttpOnly:protected] => 1 
            [useCookies:protected] => 1 
            [options:protected] => Array ( 
                [gc_maxlifetime] => 2592000 
            ) 
        ) 
        [defaultConfigClass:protected] => Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig     
        [storage:protected] => Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage Object (
        ) 
        [defaultStorageClass:protected] => Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage 
        [saveHandler:protected] => 
    ) 
    [storage:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [flag:protected] => 2 
    [iteratorClass:protected] => ArrayIterator 
    [protectedProperties:protected] => Array ( 
        [0] => name 
        [1] => manager 
        [2] => storage 
        [3] => flag 
        [4] => iteratorClass 
        [5] => protectedProperties 
    ) 
)
```

It means there is nothing like `username`...

But when I am printing the `S_SESSION` it gives me this output...

```
Array ( 
    [__ZF] => Array ( 
        [_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME] => 1429081041.81 
    ) 
    [user] => Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject Object ( 
        [storage:protected] => Array ( 
            [username] => Sandhya 
        ) 
        [flag:protected] => 2 
        [iteratorClass:protected] => ArrayIterator     
        [protectedProperties:protected] => Array ( 
            [0] => storage 
            [1] => flag 
            [2] => iteratorClass 
            [3] => protectedProperties 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

There is a field `username`...

But when I am trying to get the `$_SESSION` in view it gives me the same output as above..

The problem is I am not able to get the `username` in both the container as well as in `$_SESSION`.
I need it in the controllers.
what can be the problem need help? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this username in view part?

Comment: no i want this in controllers

Comment: Ok, I am posting the answer that will help you.

Comment: The session container is just a wrapper for `$_SESSION`. You don't see your username when you var_dump the container because *it is stored in the session*. If you can't access the username via. the container in the view, please edit your question to include the code you are using to test that.

Comment: am getting the session's value in the controller itself and passing the values to view ....

Comment: I am finding the Session's value in same controller where it has been asssign the offset and its value but not in other one

Comment: I have Downloaded the other package of ZF2 here it is working

Comment: what is the problem with the old one ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to work on your configuration.
You have to setup a common `SessionManager` to manage handling of your session information.

Something like this:

```
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions($config);
$sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
$sessionManager->start();
Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

I would suggest registering your SessionManager config in your ServiceManager instance and then use it throughout the application.

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'session_manager' => 'My\Factory\SessionManagerFactory'
    )
)
```

You can then get your SessionManager in any controller:

```
$sessionManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('session_manager');
```

And if you create a new `Container` it will use your common/default `SessionManager` instance automatically so all will be managed in one place.

```
$userSession = new Container('user');
$userSession->getManager() === $this->serviceLocator->get('session_manager') // true
```

On how to register your session_manager I will refer to [the official ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html).

Comment: I have already set this configuration but not created ServiceManager instance for that its nice way but still the problem is there ..I have installed the another package of Zend in that the container is working perfectly.but now I have to copy my all code to the new Package.So I think the problem was in package it self.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$userSession = new Container('user');
//To check the session variable in zf2:
if($userSession->offsetExists('username')){
   //Your logic after check condition
}
```

This will return true or false on the basis of session exist or not.

```
//To get the value of session:
echo $user->offsetGet('username');
```

Above code will return the value of session index `username`.

Instead of `$userSession->username = 'Sandhya';` you can use below code:

```
$user->offsetSet('username','Sandhya');
```

This is zf2 standard, which is used by session container in zf2.

Comment: echo $userSession->offsetExists('username'); giving nothing in other controller.

Comment: @SandhyaGor first use `$userSession = new Container('user');` then echo it.

Comment: is there any issue with installation?

Comment: because everything is working fine but only session.

Comment: Try it in if condition like this: `if (! ($user->offsetExists('username'))) {
echo "Session exit";
        }` also check your session has been created.

Comment: session has been created but there is no offset username

Comment: @SandhyaGor check with other offset which is exist.

Comment: its printing session Exists

Comment: @SandhyaGor sorry for this, this will not echoing you can just check it in if condition and then you can process or write logic.

Comment: but the problem is i am not able store the data in session what can be the reason for it

Comment: I am not getting the data in another controller where as i am getting the data in same controller is what can be the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75258/discussion-between-sandhya-gor-and-code-lver).

Answer (score 0):

you can just get your username from session in controllers.

```
 $userSession = new Container('user');
 $username = $userSession->username ;
 var_dump($username); //Sandhya
```

it work for me . try it !